# Display Value instead of Null when Value MINUS Null

Tags: sql

```
SELECT --PartnerId,
          ScheLineDesc,
          PartNumber,
          TotalQtyOrder,
          TotalShippedQty,
          TotalQtyOrder - TotalShippedQty AS TotalBalanceToShip
```

[image]

I need to display TotalQtyOrder in TotalBalanceToShip when TotalShippedQty is Null. Right now, I only get Null.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `coalesce()` function

```
select ScheLineDesc,
          PartNumber,
          TotalQtyOrder,
          TotalShippedQty,
           coalesce(TotalQtyOrder, 0) - coalesce(TotalShippedQty, 0) as TotalBalanceToShip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Isnull` or `NVL` function to check and replace value with `null`

Comment: Product specific tip to a question with no dbms specified.